# Querying with Timestamps using SpringBoot and JPA Criteria Query in custom repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

How do you query based off timestamps in custom JPA repositories using JPA Criteria Query?

I have a `startTime` and `endTime` that I want to use to query for entires with a field `time` between them, but I need to do this in a custom repository because there are a lot of other fields that I need to use to build a complex query.

I've can succcessfully build up a complex query and get correct results, except when I try to query by `startTime` and `endTime`. I've been trying to do something like the following but with no luck

```
@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
...
  final CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
  final CriteriaQuery<AutoenrollmentEvent> cr = cb.createQuery(Event.class);
  final Root<AutoenrollmentEvent> root = cr.from(Event.class);
  final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
  ...
    predicates.add(cb.between(root.get("time"), data.getStartTime(), data.getEndTime()));
  ...
  cr.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
  return this.em.createQuery(cr).getResultList();
```

where `data.getStartTime()` and `data.getEndTime()` are of type `java.sql.Timestamp`.

The idea is to get all the entries with a timestamp in field `time` between `startTime` and `endTime`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, `java.sql.Timestamp` was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Replaced by `java.time.Instant` or `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, with support for the first being optional in JDBC 4.2 and the second being required.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using Spring Data JPA CrudRepository interface:

```java
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
    List<Event> findAllByTimeAfterAndTimeBefore(Timestamp start, Timestamp end);
}
```

And then using it:

```java
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;

    public void myMethod() {
        Timestamp startTime = // create start timestamp
        Timestamp endTime = // create end timestamp
        List<Event> events = eventRepository.findAllByTimeAfterAndTimeBefore(startTime,endTime);
    }
}
```

Spring will implement the query automatically and return the results. [Official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts).

Comment: I understand how to do it this way, however this is not viable for me. I need to build up a complex query based off several different fields thats that may or may not be provided in the request. If I used the CrudRepository interface I would need to create an unrealistic amount of methods to achieve the functionality I want. That means I have to use a a custom repo and build up the query using CriteriaBuilder. I could what you suggest and in my manager call both my custom method and something like the above and take the intersection of both result sets, but I would rather do it all at once.